# How to set http status code explicitly with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSTRestBundle and I'd like set the status code not statically like show in the documentation by using annotation:

```
/**
 * @View(statusCode=204)
 */
public function deleteUserAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

but doing it dynamically...I mean depending on my logic I may send 200 or 301... because the way I'm using the bundle (one method for many types of actions ....), does not respect the principle of REST but I like it to be like this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a view with the status code set directly rather than leaving it for the response listener to handle like..

```
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

public function deleteUserAction()
{
    // ... do stuff and generate status code

    return View::create(null, $statusCode);
}
```